# All post message is not showing with sql GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this `comments` table to store all comments of each Post

```
comment_id    comment_message    posts_id   u_id   created
=============================================================
46            comments....       2          6      1559376498
47            comments....       2          6      1559376502
48            comments....       2          6      1559376598
```

and `comments_like` table for each comment **reaction (r_id)**

```
cl_id    comment_id   posts_id    u_id   r_id   created
=============================================================
42       46           2           6      6     1559376598
43       47           2           6      2     1559376598
44       48           2           6      8     1559376598
45       46           2           1      2     1559376598
```

**Note:** `posts_id` means posts table id, `u_id` means users table id, `r_id` means reaction id, `comment_id` means comment table id.

**Now,** I want to get all comments for a specific ID with a list of reaction id's **and** that reaction id which is given by the logged user.

For that, I am using the following SQL query but it's not showing my expected result :(

```
$query = $this->_db->_pdo->prepare("
            SELECT c.*, u.u_id, u.full_name, cl.r_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cl.r_id ORDER BY cl.u_id) AS r_id
            FROM comments AS c 
            LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.u_id = u.u_id 
            LEFT JOIN comments_like AS cl ON cl.comment_id = c.comment_id 
            WHERE c.posts_id = '$post_id' 
            ORDER BY c.comment_id  ");
```

**Output of this query should be**

1) all comments of specific post id ($post_id);
2) a list of reaction id's
3) reaction id of logged user.

Comment: what's the output of this query?

Comment: You don't have a group by so I would expect the unexpected with a group_Concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause on your query so it is grouping all the comments into one row; you need to group by `c.comment_id`. This should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT c.*, u.u_id, u.full_name, cl.r_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(cl.r_id ORDER BY cl.u_id) AS r_id
FROM comments AS c 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON c.u_id = u.u_id 
LEFT JOIN comments_like AS cl ON cl.comment_id = c.comment_id 
WHERE c.posts_id = 2
GROUP BY c.comment_id
ORDER BY c.comment_id
```

Output:

```
comment_id  comment_message posts_id    u_id    created     u_id    full_name   r_id
46          comments....    2           6       1559376498  6       Bill Jones  2,6
47          comments....    2           6       1559376502  6       Bill Jones  2
48          comments....    2           6       1559376598  6       Bill Jones  8
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWCJ497p1dqK77MaNswJQ9/4)

Comment: is this query showing that reaction id which is given by the user? btw, it's showing a list of rection id but I also need reaction id of the user too.

Comment: @creativeartbd do you mean the reaction from the user who posted the comment?

Comment: No who gave that reaction because multiple users can react. I have a  variable called `$logged_user_id`

Comment: @creativeartbd take a look at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uWCJ497p1dqK77MaNswJQ9/6. This gives you all the reactions for the comment, but also the reaction (if any) from a specific user (in the demo I've used user 1). That would be where you would use your `$logged_user_id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the reaction id for a particular user as well.  If so:

```
SELECT c.*, u.u_id, u.full_name,
       MAX(ASE WHEN cl.u_id = ? THEN cl.r_id END) as specific_user_reaction, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(cl.r_id ORDER BY cl.u_id) AS r_id
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON c.u_id = u.u_id LEFT JOIN
     comments_like cl
     ON cl.comment_id = c.comment_id 
WHERE c.posts_id = ?
GROUP BY c.comment_id, u.u_id, u.full_name
ORDER BY c.comment_id;
```

The `?` are for *parameters*.  This is how you should be passing values into prepared statement (rather than munging query strings).

The first `?` is for the user whose reaction you want.  The second is for the post that you want (`$post_id` in your original code).  You can review the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) on prepared statements if you need to learn more about passing in parameters.